# Cannot publish self-contained .NET app that

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cross-platform

No matter what, .NET will not allow me to publish the app self-contained. It fills the export directory with dozens of files. While I'm new and am not ready to publish professional apps yet, I know for a fact that this is not a user friendly approach to deploying apps. Please help me figure out why I cannot export the app in self-contained mode. Here is the command that I'm using:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c release
```

I'm also publishing it to Mac and Linux:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true -c release
dotnet publish -r osx-x64 --self-contained true -c release
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So far, I've tried it with this same command with my main project (which has one NuGet package), as well as a fake solution that only has `Console.Writeline("Hello world!");`  that should have no problems deploying. The result is the same--no self contained executable.

Comment: `--self-contained [true|false]`

Publishes the .NET runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm not sure if you read the code, but I included that flag in all my tests. It didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: The flag doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -p:UseAppHost=true --self-contained --configuration Release
```